# Issue with Mysql auto generated PK used for another table and JPA

Tags: mysql, primary-key, jpa-2.0, auto-generate

My use case is as follows: I use MySQL and JPA 2 and I have two entities: **Order** and **LineItem** that are associated by a OneToMany relationship.

I would like for the GUI layer to persist the Order together with the LineItem at the same time.

Bearing in mind that the **PK of Order is auto-generated** by MySQL and **is part of the PK of LineItem**, I don't know how to retrieve the generated Order PK in order to use it for the LineItem PK within the same transaction.

Can anyone help please?

Further to your feedback, here is some sample code from the entities (I actually made up the use case/domain above. Mine is more complicated so you won't see any Order or LineItem).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "status_need_ID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Advertisement.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Advertisement a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Advertisement.findByAdvertisementID", query = "SELECT a FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.advertisementID = :advertisementID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Advertisement.findByAdvertisementTitle", query = "SELECT a FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.advertisementTitle = :advertisementTitle"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Advertisement.findByAdvertisementCreationDate", query = "SELECT a FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.advertisementCreationDate = :advertisementCreationDate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Advertisement.findByStatusneedID", query = "SELECT a FROM Advertisement a WHERE a.statusneedID = :statusneedID")})
public class Advertisement implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer advertisementID;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "advertisement_title", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String advertisementTitle;
    @Column(name = "advertisement_creation_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date advertisementCreationDate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "advertisement_body", nullable = false, length = 2147483647)
    private String advertisementBody;
    @Column(name = "status_need_ID")
    private Integer statusneedID;
    @JoinTable(name = "postcode_to_advertisement_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "postcode_ID", referencedColumnName = "postcode_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Postcode> postcodeCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "advertisement_to_duration_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "duration_ID", referencedColumnName = "duration_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Duration> durationCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "full_or_part_time_basis_to_advertisement_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "full_or_part_time_basis_ID", referencedColumnName = "full_or_part_time_basis_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<FullOrPartTimeBasis> fullOrPartTimeBasisCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "advertisement_to_child_care_type_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "child_care_type_ID", referencedColumnName = "child_care_type_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<ChildCareType> childCareTypeCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "advertisement_to_school_holiday_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "school_holiday_ID", referencedColumnName = "school_holiday_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<SchoolHoliday> schoolHolidayCollection;
    @JoinTable(name = "employment_contract_to_advertisement_join", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "employment_contract_ID", referencedColumnName = "employment_contract_ID", nullable = false)})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<EmploymentContract> employmentContractCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "advertisement")
    private Collection<AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin> advertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinCollection;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "advertisementID")
    private Collection<Salary> salaryCollection;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "advertisement")
    private ParentToParentAdvertisement parentToParentAdvertisement;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "advertisement")
    private ParentToChildMinderAdvertisement parentToChildMinderAdvertisement;
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_care_location_ID", referencedColumnName = "child_care_location_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private ChildCareLocation childcarelocationID;
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_ID", referencedColumnName = "account_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Account accountID;



@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement_to_time_slot_to_day_join",schema="bignibou")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin a"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin.findByDayID", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin a WHERE a.advertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinPK.dayID = :dayID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin.findByTimeslotID", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin a WHERE a.advertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinPK.timeslotID = :timeslotID"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin.findByAdvertisementID", query = "SELECT a FROM AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin a WHERE a.advertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinPK.advertisementID = :advertisementID")})
public class AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoin implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected AdvertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinPK advertisementToTimeSlotToDayJoinPK;
    @JoinColumn(name = "time_slot_ID", referencedColumnName = "time_slot_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TimeSlot timeSlot;
    @JoinColumn(name = "day_ID", referencedColumnName = "day_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Day day;
    @JoinColumn(name = "advertisement_ID", referencedColumnName = "advertisement_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Advertisement advertisement;
```

Comment: could you add the code for entity mapping ?

Comment: thanks. How about doing what you describe in JPA? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea here that you'll have to save your entities in two phases. Of course you can do it in the same transaction. First you save your Order, without saving the LineItem(s), then retrieve the PK if the Order, then set it on LineItem(s) and then save LineItem(s). I guess it is the CascadeType property of then OneToMany annotation that will tell JPA to do this in two different phase, that is not to save LineItems when saving the Order. Something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade={})
    Set<LineItem> lineItems;
}
```

Or you can have the lineItems set empty when saving Order, then retrieve PK, set the lineItems, and the PK for lineItems, and then save the Order again.

Disregard this part of the answer if your database design is final and you cannot change it.

This is my private opinion (based on many years of database design and maintenance). So, in the first place, **do you have a good reason for using composite PK in LineItem instead of using a good, old [surrogate primary key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)?**

Because if you don't then you should have a surrogate primary key in LineItem. Otherwise you'll keep running into various problems (e.g. if you happen to have to migrate data)

**EDIT** My suggestion:

1. in the DB: use auto_increment PK in your tables as in this example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html
2. in the JPA mapping: go for the first option (AUTO) in this article: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated

Comment: 1. I was pretty sure there was a way to sort this problem with JPA configuration. Maybe I should use a @TableGenerator with a separated table? Would that be a good surrogate key? Or do you advise me to go for a UUID?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use @TableGenerator here. I don't get what you mean by UUID in this context. My suggestion is added to the end of answer.

Comment: I appreciate your replying but the issue is not to generate the number but rather to reuse the generated number for the second table. Do you see my point? Therefore the links you suggested are slightly irrelevant.

Comment: I see your point, and the first part of my answer was meant to help you with achieving your goal. The second part though, with the links, is my suggestion to give up your initial goals and do this properly.